# Split remaining space between two table-cells

Tags: html, css

I need to have a `div` with dynamic width centered and a `div` on either side taking up the remaining space.

```
| fill remaining space   | dynamically sized |   fill remaining space |
```

I need the dynamically sized `div` to wrap if the text is too long to fit on one line, but not otherwise.

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="content">This text should not wrap unless it is too long to fit on one line</div>
    <div class="side"></div>
</div>
```

I can achieve the desired behaviour using `display: inline-flex;` as follows (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzqpryfh/)).

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.side {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 20px;
}
.content {
}
```

However, I would prefer to use `display: table;` for compatibility reasons and I can't quite get it to work. My attempt so far is as follows (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5jdcewu/)).

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.side {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
.content {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

As you can see, the width of the `content` cell becomes the width of the longest word. I can't use `white-space: nowrap;` because then it won't wrap even if the content is too long to fit on a single line.

Is there any way to get this to work using `display: table;`? I would also be happy to try anything else that is reasonably compatible.

**Update** I need the `content` column to take up the minimum space possible so `table-layout: fixed;` won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting `table-layout: fixed;` on the .container.
You also need to reduce the width of the .side elements to 25% as you have two of them, not one. Have a look at [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hcwtkLe/).

`table-layout:fixed` will cause the fluid column to take up the space left by the fixed width columns. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) and [this article](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/) by Chris Coyier!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `content` column no longer dynamically resizes around the text in this case.

Comment: i.e., if I have short text I don't want a margin (other than as specified in the css).

Comment: Yes with `table-layout: fixed` the .content row will only fill the gap between the two .side elements. I actually have no idea at the moment on how to achieve your aim, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those things that seems like it should be simple but I can't find a way to do it (except using `display: inline-flex;` which admittedly works perfectly, but has fairly limited support on older browsers). Thanks anyway for trying!

Comment: I am baffled aswell.. seems like a very simple problem. But then again, in this world "that's simple" are probably the most common last words.